# Did I download Blender correctly, or was it CG Cookie?

Tags: installation

I downloaded Blender yesterday (or so I thought). When I click on the icon this morning, all I get is the beginning screen of a tutorial from CG Cookie.

Who is CG Cookie and how do I have them? How do I get Blender and the initial page I had when I first finished downloading it?

Comment: can you look thought your browser history and post a link to the page from which you downloaded blender? CG cookie is a training site not at all connected to the blender foundation, although they do have tutorials and addons for blender, they do not have a custom version of blender for download.

Comment: CGCookie is a website with tutorials and learning material, which among other software also includes Blender resources. I am guessing you didn't download Blender at all and you somehow clicked a shortcut to the website. Try following the instructions from Uncle Snail bellow.

Comment: Also if you downloaded Blender from sourceforge or similar sites, the default download often includes a installer which pack loads of adware... always make sure you find the projects [own proper website](https://www.blender.org/) and get the right links from there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not actually about blender, its about downloading.

Answer (score 9):

Try downloading Blender from this page https://www.blender.org/download/.

Make sure you get the correct version for your operating system.

You can also download a program file that does not require installing by downloading the zip.

Simply unzip the folder to your desktop, and run the program (it will be the file "blender" and will be a program file. [or application/executable, depending on your os.])

Or you can download the "bleeding edge" test builds from [here](https://builder.blender.org/download/). It is the most recent version of Blender, and is a kind of test build, so be ware, it may not be stable.